# What is the preferred way of consuming a continuous stream of JSON using C# and HttpClient?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I need to continuously consume a JSON-stream using the `async HttpClient` found in .Net4.5. What is the preferred way of doing this?

The request is a simple `GET` and using `Curl` you don't have to specify more than `GET`. No specific headers, no nothing. It just works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying some stuff out, it was quite easy. Missed one little thing which made it hang. You needed to use the overload of `SendAsync`, where you can specify `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

Wrote a [small post](http://danielwertheim.se/using-c-and-httpclient-to-consume-continuously-streamed-results/) about it.